# Constructor/destructor defined by trait is not being called

Tags: php, traits

How can I launch constructor and destructor defined by trait along with the class' constructor and destructor as well. For example,

```
trait Audit
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); // Doesn't work...

        $this->_name = __CLASS__;

        $this->AuditAction('Started');
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        parent::__destruct(); // Doesn't work...

        $this->AuditAction('Ended');

        echo $this->_log;        
    }

    public function AuditAction($n)
    {
        $this->_log .= $this->GetCurrentTimeStamp() . ' ' . $this->_name . ": $n" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private function GetCurrentTimeStamp()
    {
        return (new DateTime())->format('[Y-m-d H:i:s]');
    }

    private $_name, $_log = '';
}

class C
{
    use Audit;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function __destruct()
    {

    }
}

$c = new C();
```

I should get couple of lines of text but I get none since class C's constructor is explicitly called instead. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor and destructor of C will have precedence over the trait constructor and destructor when the class is composed:

> An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. **The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods**, which in return override inherited methods.

Source: http://php.net/traits

In other words, remove the empty constructor and destructor from C and the trait's constructor and destructor will be used. There is no way to make this work with both, C and the traits, constructor and destructor, because traits do not work like regular inheritance.

In general, I would advise against giving Traits their own constructors or destructors because you cannot instantiate Traits. You instantiate from a class *having* a Trait and that class should be in control. Consider adding an `onCreate()` or `onDestroy()` method to the trait instead and call these from the appropriate magic methods on C. You could achieve the same by aliasing the traits __construct in C, but I think this waters down semantics.

Comment: This is not correct. It is possible to call methods of the Trait that are overwritten by the class that uses the Trait. It is sufficient to change the name of the methods in the Trait with something else.

Comment: @Aerendir If my reading of the C source is correct, an aliased ctor or dtor will not contain the ctor or dtor function flags anymore. This implies that it is technically *not possible*, because they are just regular methods then. However, you are obviously right that you can execute them *as regular methods* by aliasing and that will effectively solve the OP's problem. But that's more like calling a custom`onCreate()` or `onDestroy()` method than calling actual ctors or dtors.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define a custom name for the methods of the `Trait`. Then you can call those method from your class.

As the methods of the class overwrite the methods of the `Trait` you have to assign a different name to the methods of the `Trait`:

```
class C
{
    use Audit {
        Audit::__construct as auditConstruct;
        Audit::__destruct as auditDestruct;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->auditConstruct();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
         $this->auditDestruct();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Addition to [Aeremdir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399706/aerendir)'s answer: inherited constructors from base class and multiple traits...

```
<?php
  trait T1 {
    public function __construct() {
      $this->someval |= 0b0001;
      echo "T1::__construct() done\n";
    }
  }

  trait T2 {
    public function __construct() {
      $this->someval |= 0b0010;
      echo "T2::__construct() done\n";
    }
  }

  class C1 {
    protected $someval;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->someval = 0b10000000;
      echo "C1::__construct() done\n";
    }
  }

  class C2 extends C1 {
    use T1, T2 {
      T1::__construct as private T1__construct;
      T2::__construct as private T2__construct;
    }

    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->T1__construct();
      $this->T2__construct();

      $this->someval |= 0b00100000;
      echo "C2::__construct() done\n";
    }

    public function someval() {
      $str = base_convert($this->someval, 10, 2);
      $len = strlen($str);
      if($len < 8)
          $str = str_repeat('0', 8 - $len) . $str;

      return '0b' . $str;
    }
  }

  $v1 = new C2();
  echo $v1->someval();
?>
```

under PHP 7.0.5 this code results in...

> C1::__construct() done
>   T1::__construct() done
>   T2::__construct() done
>   C2::__construct() done
>   0b10100011